# Android initialize Animation

Tags: android, variables, object, animation, initialization

I couldn't find examples of how to initialize the animation object.

example `Animation ticketAnim;`

well `new Animation();` is not a valid object it seems so  I can't just do `Animation ticketAnim = new Animation();` but I would like to. I take the suggested initialization route that the IDE offers which is `Animation ticketAnim = null;`

of course, accessing this will result in a null pointer exception

what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring a new animation, you need to use the constructor of an animation type.  Here's some sample code for one of the animation controllers I use in my code:

```
private void addDeleteDropAnimation() {
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(150);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
    );
    animation.setDuration(300);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    controllerDel = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);
    vw_delLinearLayout.setLayoutAnimation(controllerDel);
}
```

The `Animation` class itself is just an abstraction.  To use an animation, implement one of Animation's direct know subclasses (also specified in the link to the [Animation API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html)).

These include:

- [AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html)
- [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)
- [RotateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html)
- [ScaleAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html)

If you want, you can also create your own custom animation by extending the `Animation` class.  A good example of creating a custom animation can be found [here](http://hejp.co.uk/android/using-animations-and-creating-custom-animations-for-android/).